# JavaScript - loop through shuffled values across different pages

Tags: javascript, random, shuffle

I have five different pages. Each has a button that redirects to one of the others, randomly.

I am trying to make it so that the user doesn't get to repeated pages (at least not after going through them all).

I can add a function to go through random, non-repeating stuff in the same page, but how can I make that function work across different pages, remembering which pages were already visited?

I tried saving that function in an external js file and call it in the head section of every page, but it does not work.

This is what I have:

```js
    var page1="01.html"
    var page2="02.html"
    var page3="03.html"
    var page4="04.html"
    var page5="05.html"
        
        const originalPages = [page1, page2, page3, page4, page5];
        let remainingPages = [];

        function randomize() {
            if (remainingPages.length === 0) remainingPages = originalPages.slice();
            const {
                length
            } = remainingPages;
            const [page] = remainingPages.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * length), 1);
            window.location.href = page;
        }
```

```html
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
    <p><button onclick="randomize()" type="button">Random Page</button></p>
```

Comment: Save the current `remainingPages` in `localStorage`, retrieve it on page load, and set it after `splice`ing.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I just added `localStorage.getItem("currentRemainingPages");` right at the beginning of the script, and `localStorage.setItem("currentRemainingPages", remainingPages);` after `const [page] = remainingPages.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * length), 1);` but it does not work as intended. Am I doing something wrong?